# Is there any bluetooth plugin for iOS?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm wondering if there is any plugin for using bluetooth with phonegap on iOS to be connected/paired with other devices.

Answer (score 2):

You Can use `Bluetooth Serial plugins` available for `IOS`-

1) https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial

2) https://github.com/KristinaHeyerdahlElfving/Bluetooth-Smart-Plugin/tree/master/Bluetooth%20Low%20Energy%20Plugin

also check Phonegap Bluetooth Serial plugin [Here](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/23)

Comment: the first one is to connect device with arduino, the second one is too old, phonegap3 changed their architecture a lot so I have to update this plugin which I will try to do

Comment: The first work with all serial Bluetooth devices not just Arduino. I'm using it with other devices

Answer (score 2):

I recently created a Phonegap 3.0+ [plugin](https://github.com/randdusing/BluetoothLE) that supports Bluetooth Low Energy on Android and iOS that may be of benefit to you. It doesn't support pairing, but it can scan for devices, connect to devices, read data, etc.

Comment: I doesn't show any devices for me. Which devices have you tested this on? (Currently testing Nexus 5 to a Nexus 4)

Comment: Tested with a newer iPad, newer iPhone and Nexus 7. The Nexus 4 may not be advertising any Bluetooth LE services.